# How can I pass the `username` as props from a functional stateless parent to a functional stateless child to another stateful child?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-props, react-state-management

How can I pass the `username` as props from a functional stateless parent to a functional stateless child to another stateful child?

Currently it shows `undefined` in both First Child and Second Child.

Parent Component:

```
  let userName = 'Some UserName';

  export default function App() {
   return (
    <Router>
  <div>
    <AuthButton />
    <Route path="/" render={() => (
      <Redirect to="/auth" />
    )} />
    <Route path="/auth" component={Login} />
    <PrivateRoute
      path='/home'
      component={Home}
      render={(props) => <Home userName={props.userName} />}
    />
  </div>
</Router>
 )
}
```

First Child Component:

```
 function Home(props) {

let userName = props.userName

console.log(userName);   // SHOWS UNDEFINED!

return (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <div className="row cont">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header">
                                Messages
                        </div>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <MessengerApp userName={props.userName} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </Router >


   );
 }
```

Second Child Component:

```
class MessengerApp extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   // set the initial state of the application
    this.state = { username: this.props.userName };

 console.log(this.state.username)  // SHOWS UNDEFINED!  

 }

 render(){
     // JSX
  }
```

I want all of the components to log the username as `Some UserName`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't correctly passing the prop UserName to Home from the App component. The render callback function for Route provides the Router props and not the component props

```
let userName = 'Some UserName';

export default function App(props) {
   return (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <AuthButton />
            <Route path="/" render={() => (
              <Redirect to="/auth" />
            )} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/home'
              component={Home}
              render={(routerProps) => <Home {...routerProps} userName={userName} />}
            />
          </div>
    </Router>
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found the reason why it wasnt working and was able to fix. Please see my answer. Also, {props} should work,  is {routerProps} a thing in React? Couldnt find it anywhere.

Comment: routerProps is just a name to differentiate between components props and the Props provider by Router, you could name it anything

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out the reason it wasnt working. Due to `PrivateRoute` being a customized Route component, it was not recognizing `render` as a method to pass `props`. I had to move the `render props` to the actual `Route` tag inside that `PrivateRoute` function. Please see below:

```
let userName = 'Some UserName';


  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
       authFunc.isAuthenticated === true
          ? <Component {...props} userName={userName}/>
         : <Redirect to={{
           pathname: '/auth',
           state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
      )} />
     )

export default function App(props) {
   return (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <AuthButton />
            <Route path="/" render={() => (
              <Redirect to="/auth" />
            )} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/home'
              component={Home}
            />
          </div>
    </Router>
 )
}
```